# Undocking a TabPage in from Tab Control

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF, since there is no MDI concept, I used a `TabControl`. But in WinForms with MDI, I could put two MDI Child forms side by side to compare some data. Resizing of the MDI Child is also possible. How can I achieve the same with WPF `TabControl`. I want the `TabPage` to undock as we can do in Visual Studio IDE and enable user to resize the child window. I am not permitted to use any third party tools or source code for this task. So can anyone guide me with example if possible?

So far, I have added a `TabControl`. I am adding/removing `Tab`s to/from the `TabControl` through `MenuItem` click. I have added a `ContextMenu` to the `Tab`s with an *Undock* `MenuItem`. When this is clicked, I am displaying the same `UserControl` which I used as the `TabPage` content, but with a title bar and a close button. Now I am stuck on adding the `UserControl` back to the tabs group.

Comment: Did you tried GridSplitter?

Comment: What about DevExpress DockLayoutControl? https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument8149

Comment: You can use AvalonDock (https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Version2.0/). It is open source, so if you cannot add dlls, you can add the source to your project.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I cannot resort to any kind of third party tools(even source). So please give me a solution that does not involve third party tools.

Comment: I am sorry, but you cannot this with a TabControl.  Without using a custom (third-party) control, there is no easy way out.  You need to simulate the MDE behavior using a custom control, which you can derive from Panel, and implement a title bar, border, and moving and sizing features.